# Push to a javascript array if it exists, if not then create it first

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is there a way for this line to always work and not throw `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Whatever' of undefined`

```
var MyArray = [];
MyArray[StringVariableName][StringVariableName2].push("whatever");
```

Comment: `MyArray = MyArray || [];`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
var MyArray = [];
MyArray[StringVariableName] = MyArray[StringVariableName] || [];
MyArray[StringVariableName][StringVariableName2] = MyArray[StringVariableName][StringVariableName2] || [];
MyArray[StringVariableName][StringVariableName2].push("whatever");
```

Comment: Works amazing, can you explain what that assignment means?

Comment: @NadavMiller It simply is a logical OR. If first part is true, second part is not executed and first part is assigned to the variable.

Comment: It is the logical OR operator and it simply says: If the left operand is a truthy value then return it otherwise return the right operand.

Answer (score 4):

You could even, through the power of expressions, do this with a one-liner.

```
(MyArray[StringVariableName][StringVariableName2] || (MyArray[StringVariableName][StringVariableName2] = [])).push("whatever");
```

Comment: This is awesome.

Is there any performance lag in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using array in the first place, use object if your keys are not integers. 
In Javascript Arrays are also object So it is not wrong to do this

```
var a = [];
a['key'] = 'something';

console.log(a); //Gives []
```

**I think it is conceptually wrong** So instead of using Array to hold such pair of data you should use objects. See this:

```
var myObject = myObject || {};
myObject[str1] = myObject[str1] || {};
myObject[str1][str2] = myObject[str][str2] || [];

// Now myObject[str1][str2] is an array. Do your original operation

myObject[str1][str2].push("whatever");
```

Comment: .push() is for arrays, not objects.

Comment: @A__ Both of us are correct as `myObject[str1][str2]` is an array and not an object here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the literal syntax to set things up like you'd have them:

```
var myObj = {
    StringVariableName: {
        StringVariableName2: []
    }
};

myObj.StringVariableName.StringVariableName2.push("whatever");
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong way because StringVariableName looks like actually a variable name. You are making them as constant keys in the object.

Answer (score 0):

**To check without getting an error:**

this snippet allows you to check if a chained object exists.

```
var x;
try{x=MyArray[name1][name2][name3][name4]}catch(e){}
!x||(x.push('whatever'));
```

from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21353032/2450730

**Shorthand creation of object chains in Javascript**

this function allows you to create chained objects with a simple string.

```
function def(a,b,c,d){
 c=b.split('.');
 d=c.shift();//add *1 for arrays
 a[d]||(a[d]={});//[] for arrays
 !(c.length>0)||def(a[d],c.join('.'));
}
```

usage

```
var MyArray={};//[]
def(MyArray,'name1.name2.name3.name4');//name1+'.'+name2....
```

from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21384869/2450730

both work also for arrays with a simple change.replace `{}` with `[]`

if you have any questions just ask.